# Can Windows Phone 8 support ftp function?

Tags: windows-phone-8

Because FTP library is not available in Windows Phone 7, and I recently found out that Windows Phone 8 SDK was released, I wonder if it can support FTP library?

Comment: Can't you just *use* an FTP library?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement FTP Library. Refer to this article on 'Adding FTP Support in Windows Phone 8' [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn385710.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn385710.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the link above and the FTP will not work when bitmap source is set. In other words, if I want to preview a picture before FTP it...it will not work. If not bitmap is set, then FTP works fine.